# Serial number start from 1 in every page in my pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi iam using simple pagination code .It getting the problem is that the serial number start from 1 in every page in my pagination ,but i need it from 1-10 in 2nd page, from 11-20 in 3rd page and so on

my code

```
<div class="col-md-4"> 
 <select id="userlist_page" class="form-control">
 <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $tot_pages; $i++) {
    $select = '';
    if ($cur_page == $i) {
    $select = 'selected';
   }
  echo '<option ' .$select. ' value="' .$i. '">Page ' .$i. '</option>';
  }
 ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass page number as url parameter and use it like.

> Url looks like /?page=2

```
<div class="col-md-4"> 
 <select id="userlist_page" class="form-control">
 <?php
    for ($i = $_GET['page']; $i <= $tot_pages; $i++) {
    $select = '';
    if ($cur_page == $i) {
    $select = 'selected';
   }
  echo '<option ' .$select. ' value="' .$i. '">Page ' .$i. '</option>';
  }
 ?>
</select>
</div>
```